# POST or GET selected value from select option before submit (same page)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have done searching this question here but there is no suitable answer for my problem. So to be more specific, I have 2 select option which is floor and room. Both selection displayed based on database. So is there a syntax that can get the selected floor id so I can do my query to display the specific room for the selected floor before submit? Here's my code :

```
<form name="form" method="POST">        
    <div class="form-group">
        <div><label>Floor Name</label></div>
            <select class="form-control" id="floorid" name="existfloorname">
                <option>None</option>
            <?php 
                $result = $conn->query("select * from floors");
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
                {
                    ?><option id="<?php echo $row['floorid'];?>" value="<?php echo $row['floorname']; ?>"><?php echo $row['floorname']; ?></option><?php
                }               
            ?>
            </select>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <div><label>Room Name</label></div>
            <select class="form-control" name="existroomname">
                <option>None</option>
            <?php 
                $result = $conn->query("select * from rooms where floorid = '".GETSELECTEDFLOORID."'");
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
                {
                    ?><option value="<?php echo $row['roomname']; ?>"><?php echo $row['roomname']; ?></option><?php
                }
            ?>
            </select>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete">
</form>
```

[This is how the form looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MllL4.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to work with AJAX for this. AJAX allows the sending of data from the front(JS) to the back(PHP). JQuery makes this easy by providing you with the `.ajax()` method.  This is how you need to do this:

*Note: You will need to use **jQuery** to do it this way*

**First**, re-arrange your HTML in this manner, notice the `select` ids:

```
<form name="form" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div><label>Floor Name</label></div>
        <select class="form-control" id="floor_select" name="existfloorname">
            <option>None</option>
            <?php
            $floors = $conn->query("select * from floors");
            while ($row = $floors->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
                 <option value="<?= $row['floorid']; ?>"><?= $row['floorname']; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div><label>Room Name</label></div>
        <select class="form-control" id="room_select" name="existroomname">
            <option>None</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete">
</form>
```

**Second**, create your jQuery ajax call:

```
    $(document).on("change", 'select#floor_select', function(e) {
        var floor_id = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {floor_id: floor_id},
            url: 'get_room_list.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json) {
                var $el = $("select#room_select");
                $el.empty(); // remove old options
                $el.append("<option>Please Select</option>");
                //iterate through your results and add to your dropdown
                $.each(json, function(k, v) {
                    $el.append("<option value='" + v.id + "'>" + v.roomname + "</option>");
                });
            }
        });

    });
```

**Third**, create the PHP script that the AJAX call above is looking for. 
 Call it `get_room_list.php`:

```
<?php
$result = $conn->query("select * from rooms where floorid = '" . GETSELECTEDFLOORID . "'");
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $results[] = $row;
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($results);
```

---

Once all the above is done, you should be able to obtain the information you need. Every time the "Floor Name" select is changed, JS will send a POST request (via AJAX) to PHP and PHP will return the "rooms" result in JSON format, which you then iterate to create your dropdown.

Hope this all makes sense.

Good luck.

Comment: agree with this..great answer

Comment: I will try this. Thank you

Comment: No problem. Let me know if you run into any issues.

Comment: Actually it does not work. I follow everything. For your info, this is how the form looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/MllL4.png

Comment: what does your console say? if youre in Chrome, right click and go to `inspect` you probably see errors there.

Comment: it says "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list". what does it mean?

Comment: yes, I fixed it. I had extra `$(` in `$el.append($("<option>Please Select</option>");`

Comment: nothing work too. the room name select option still none

Comment: id- 489 178 430  pass 7015

Answer (score 0):

You may need AJAX to get list room each floor.

Comment: @RichmondGingingon [link] (https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp) follow this